# Set first letter of paragraph to different color in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles

In my document I want to color the first letter in my paragraph (among other things). I already found out how to set the first letter as initial, but now I also want to change its color based on the template used for the paragraph. Is that possible?

Comment: Does the below answer your question?

Comment: @Darth_Vader: Will test tomorrow, I have no access to InDesign from my home computer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a slightly different approach to solving this.  While he is definitely not wrong, Darth's method will involve you having to apply your style to each character manually—a process that could be very time consuming on a large document.

I'll show you how to do it automatically.

- Open your **Paragraph Style Options** and go to the **Drop Caps and Nested Styles** tab
- Click on **New Nested Style**

  [image]
- Click on the section that says **Word** and select **Characters** from the drop down

  [image]
- Click where it says **[None]** and select **New Character Style...**
- Choose whatever style settings you would like the first character of each paragraph to have and click **Ok**.  In this case, I chose to have the first character of each paragraph be displayed in Impact font, 18pt, Magenta.

  [image]

The final result:

[image]

Every paragraph with this style will have the uniquely styled first letter.  To change the styles, you can simply edit your newly created Character Style

Comment: Hmm, my first letter still is black, not magenta, even if I added the nested char style...

Comment: @arc_lupus maybe make sure you don't have any style overrides enabled?  You can disable them by clicking [this button](http://i.imgur.com/anRouvC.png).  Otherwise, I'm not sure why it's not working for you.  I'd have to see it for myself.

Comment: Where exactly can I find that button?

Comment: @arc_lupus http://i.imgur.com/oDxzkPd.png

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by setting the first letter as a character style.  I call mine `drop_cap`:

[image]

After applying the character style you can open the style and go to `Character Color` to change it:

[image]

I think you should read up on [character](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/indesign-formatting-text-character-styles.html) and [paragraph](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/indesign-formatting-text-paragraph-styles.html) styles, from Adobe: "[Paragraph and character styles](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html)".

Comment: You would have to manually apply this to each character though, right?  Is there a way to automate it?  It seems to me that's what OP was asking about...maybe I misinterpreted it.

Comment: I didnt see that from the OP or I would've made the edit for the tag.  I do imagine that you could do it through scripting.

Comment: They said "but now I also want to change its color based on the template used for the paragraph" so I took that to mean automatically, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: well if the document was built correctly and styled correctly one edit to the style itself should effect everything applied to that.

Comment: Decided to post my own answer, to show what I meant haha

Comment: I think the approach from John Manly is more suited for me, but it will be tested tomorrow.